# Bash Script not recognizing "&"

Tags: linux, bash, selenium

Hullo
iam trying to write a bash script to clone my rrepository and then run tests using selenium. when i try installing selenium dependencies, specifically when i run this command(Xvfb :99 -ac & export DISPLAY=:99)in code, i get an error (Unrecognized option: &). This is part of my code

```
xvfbb="sudo apt-get install -y xvfb"
enn="Xvfb :99 -ac & export DISPLAY=:99"
magic="sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick"
*#Function to call installation variables*

    function seleniumTests() {
    $xvfbb
    $enn
    $magic
    echo "done installing dependencies."
    }
```

I then call the above function(seleniumTests) when i finish cloning. Any idea why "&" is recognized as an error ?. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell does not parse parameter expansions for shell syntax. You can only store very simple commands the way you are trying, and even that is not advisable. Use functions instead.

```
xvfbb () { sudo apt-get install -y xvfb; }
enn () { Xvfb :99 -ac & export DISPLAY=:99; }
magic () { sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick; }
function seleniumTests() {
    xvfbb
    enn
    magic
    echo "done installing dependencies."
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it _properly_.  But maybe the commands are read from a text file or come from a data base or similar, so maybe they _need_ to be strings.  If this is the case (string requirement), my answer is the solution, otherwise I'd prefer this here.

Comment: Passing arbitrary code as strings to a script to be executed is a dangerous practice that is best avoided.

Comment: Har har ;-)  Calling an "arbitrary string" is by no way more dangerous than calling an "arbitrary function" (which is exactly as dangerous).  Your warning makes sense, but don't limit it to strings.  If the strings are set directly in the OP's script then they are not dangerous (not more than the rest of the code).  If the code shall come from a data base (or similar) then using that as a source for code is the security problem.

Comment: If the strings are set directly in the script, there's no reason *not* to use a function. The only reason for using a string would be to pull code in from an external source, which is a security hole.

Comment: Right, _that's_ the security hole.  And it doesn't go away if instead of calling strings I call functions defined in another user's script I source (for instance).  The externality of the code and thus being under the free influence of another user—that's the real problem.  If the strings are really just in this script, as I said, then using functions instead is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Things like `&` (there are some more) are not evaluated when a variable is expanded.

To explicitly evaluate it use `eval`; then I propose to use quotes around the variables:

```
eval "$enn"
```

Comment: Thanks  @chepner for the solution. Yours is actually an advanced one.  i had gotten a work around by splitting the command into two parts as enn="Xvfb :99 -ac"
exp="export DISPLAY=:99" and then inside the function  $enn & $exp
. But yours seems cleaner so iam going to integrate your changes too. Thanks guys